# How to parse a folder path with spaces in C code

Tags: c, parsing, path, directory

I'm using this simple C code:

```
char * command = NULL;
sprintf (command, "ls %s", folderpath);
system(command);
```

The problem is when the folder name has a space in it...
I know that in Unix I need to add a "\", for example ls my\ folder\ name

How can I get around this ? Thank you!

Comment: It is not quite clear what the question is: a) How to safely run another program? (answered below by Ignacio) or b) How to list directory entries? (answered below by Lars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way out is to put the folder name inside single quotes - `sprintf( command, "ls '%s'", folder );`. Watch out for *command injection* as @ndim reminds us.

Comment: Brilliantly easy and will work until someone provides you with a *folderpath* of, say, "';cd;rm -rf *".

Answer (score 2):

Use `fork()` and `exec*()` instead.

Comment: How does that address his problem, besides making things more complicated?

Comment: @Neil: You can specify the arguments manually in an array instead of adding quotes and praying that it doesn't turn things pear-shaped. Obviously just the fork() and exec*() isn't enough, but it should lead one on to find wait*().

Answer (score 2):

If your specific problem is really to get a list of filenames in a folder, you'd be better off using the system calls opendir/readdir/closedir instead. See their manual pages for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this:

```
char * command = NULL;
sprintf (command, "ls %s", folderpath);
```

you are in undefined behaviour  land. You need to allocate some memory to command:

```
char command[1000];    // for example
sprintf (command, "ls %s", folderpath);
```